# Is it possible to do the following with auto in C++0x?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, type-inference

Eric Lippert has written an article about [Why no var on fields?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx) in C#. I was curious, will we be able to do that in C++0x? ex.

```
struct mystruct_t
{
   auto i = 0, d = 0.0, s = std::string("zero");
};
```

I couldn't reach an answer through the latest draft, sorry.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think auto is allowed in there. But even if it were, this wouldn't work because it would result in a deduction failure. For all three cases 'auto' has to be the same type.

Comment: So putting them in separate declarations is fine? I mean can we actually use auto in anyway inside a struct like I showed in the example?

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted. It sounds like a valid question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sadly you cannot. The spec says at 7.1.6.4/3 and follows

> Otherwise, the type of the variable is deduced from its initializer. The name of the variable being declared shall not appear in the initializer expression. This use of auto is allowed when declaring variables in a block (6.3), in namespace scope (3.3.6), and in a for-init-statement (6.5.3).
>
> The auto type-specifier can also be used in declaring a variable in the condition of a selection statement (6.4) or an iteration statement (6.5), in the type-speciﬁer-seq in the new-type-id or type-id of a new-expression (5.3.4), in a for-range-declaration, and in declaring a static data member with a brace-or-equal-initializer that appears within the member-specification of a class definition (9.4.2).
>
> A program that uses auto in a context not explicitly allowed in this section is ill-formed.

I'm not sure why they forbid `auto` for non-static data members, it would be quite handy.

Comment: Your answer seems much, much better than mine. I have to find time to read actual C++0x spec...

Comment: How would the compiler determine the type of non-static "auto" members?

Comment: @edA from their initalizers, of course. You would need to specify an in-class initializer, which is allowed in C++0x.

Comment: Ah yeah, never thought of that.  Looking more I see it is actually a really *stupid* restriction because `decltype` does appear to be allowed for non-static data members! Thus couldn't you define this macro: `#define mem_auto( name, value ) decltype(value) name = value`

Comment: @edA yes, I agree. What's worse is it doesn't cover all cases, so sometimes you can't work it around. While `auto x = []{ };` would be allowed (lambda), `mem_auto(x, []{});` wouldn't be allowed (lambda cannot appear within `decltype`).

Comment: @edA see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2713.html . IMO the ODR reasoning they apply there is completely off. I'm disappointed.

Comment: It appears the guys in the newsgroups even saw the same `decltype` workaround. So yes, the argument is complete nonsense.

Comment: This is forbidden because the initializer is not parsed until the class is complete (just like the bodies of member functions defined within the class), and the types of the members need to be known sooner than that. Consider: `struct S { auto a = T<sizeof(S)>(); };`

Comment: @rich good point. i will update my answer as soon as i get home from this teeth OP. thanks